# Java: difference between `Class.getDeclaringClass` and `Class.getEnclosingClass`

Tags: java, class, reflection, metaprogramming, bytecode

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaringClass--)'s the javadoc for these two methods, and I'm having trouble understanding the difference between. Is it possible for the declaring class and immediate enclosing class to be different?